# Best practices to provide Rails content managed fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

To clarify first and foremost, we are not looking for a CMS. We have an application which is already complete and live.

I want to create an area on the backend for logged in admins to manage fields which appear on the front end of the website.

I thought about creating a table: CMS_Fields. Each CMS_Field can have `:name`, `:content`, and `:timestamp` fields. Then I would display that particular field where I want it by calling it in the view by its `:name`. To make that particular field editable on the backend, I would create a disabled input with the `:name` of the field inside the disabled input and have the user themselves input the :content before they save. This also means that I must initialize all of the fields with the correct default values for `:name`. Does that make sense to do?

In order to use those fields within different views which don't belong to the CMSFieldController I would use a helper variable. Does this break convention hard and how ok is that?

Does this seem like the correct approach or should I consider a different way of doing things, or maybe even a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by first creating a model for all future cms managed fields and a migration with default values. The fields have a static `:name` variable which is determined by the developer (me). Then I call them by name in my views with the application_helper. And that's it, dead simple CMS functionality. Now any time I add a field I can slap it on any page and have it all managed on one page of my existing admin panel called "CMS."

create_site_field_migration.rb:

```
class CreateSiteFields < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :site_fields do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text :content, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    # readonly names and default values of content managed fields
    SiteField.create(name: "home_header_text", content: "Lorem ipsum sit dolor le amet.")
    SiteField.create(name: "home_body_text", content: "Requisitor mon lormen doit namet.")
  end
end
```

I have the admins able to edit the fields in my admin panel that's already auth guarded separately.

To expose the fields for the front end, I'm using `application_helper` to expose a variable:

application_helper.rb:

```
  def site_field(name)
    SiteField.find_by(name: name).content.html_safe
  end
```

And then I'm referencing the statically named fields wherever I need in my views:

home.html.erb:

```
<%= site_field(:home_body_text) %>
```

Comment: Consider sanitizing the `content` here before passing it on the the end user.  Would be easy with this for an admin to add a xss.  This is what i normally use https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Similar approach `sanitize(content).html_safe`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at administrate https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate

I've used this several times and it is pretty great and flexible.  Also ActiveAdmin was pretty ok https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. We already have a dashboard fleshed out, I just needed content management of text areas throughout the site rather than management of all of the objects themselves / dashboards. I posted my own solution below.